# Xcode Build and Archive for Enterprise Distribution builds old archive

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I'm working on creating an app for in house distribution enterprise level. I've created the app and tested hosting it on my own server and even getting the click to install working. Now though I have some updates to the app, I make the edits and I even see them in the simulator. When I build and archive the app things seem fine, then I go to the archived project in the organizer window, click the share button and distribute for enterprise, I enter details such as the ipa final url and the app title and then ok & save. Then I upload the app to my server and update any links to point to this new app. The click to install still works properly, but it installs the old version of the app. I've even tried this on a new device. Is there some step I'm mission that tells Xcode some version to build? If so, I don't get is how the simulator shows the update fine, but the archive that is built is not showing the latest code. The app I can find in the simulator dirs is 9.4MB in file size, but the one that is saved after build and archive is only 1.4MB (the update involves a lot of added images), so is the build for archive is not even getting the new files?

Comment: Are there multiple listings for your app in Organizer > Archives? Are you sure you're selecting the correct one? It also sounds like you don't have the newest version of xcode.

Comment: xcode 3.2.6 and yes, I've even gone as far as to delete all archives and build the fresh one so there was no chance of distributing an old archive

Comment: are you validating the build again before distributing it for enterprise?

Comment: First thing I would do is update your Xcode to the newest version, 4.3.2.

Comment: no, I'm not validating again, but I don't see why I should need to. Weire, I thought I was on the latest. I just installed it a couple weeks ago via the app store. I'll check on that. It sure beats banging my head on the wall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out and thought I should post it in case it helped someone else.

I cleaned the project.

Build > Clean - not 100% on what "Clean" is supposed to mean/do, but it allowed the project to build from the current files rather than the old files somehow.

Answer (score 2):

if a clean won't work, try completely removing the derived data folder.

[image]

the default location is in `/Users/you/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` .  if you haven't played with the DerivedData location in preferences, this is likely where you'll find the sub-folder containing the cache.

when i encounter a situation similar to the original question (retaining items i've deleted, or similarly missing items i've added or holding onto project icons i've changed), i perform a clean on my project, close it, hit **Delete…** in the organizer, possibly even remove it from the organizer, possibly even remove from disk and then re-checkout from git if you have it under version control in this way, then re-open the project from scratch.