# Xcode Archives a Previous Version

Tags: ios, xcode

This question seems related to [XCode Build and Archive for Enterprise Distribution builds old archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999417/xcode-build-and-archive-for-enterprise-distribution-builds-old-archive) but the answers have not worked for me;

We have an iOS application that is distributed using the Enterprise Distribution method. This has been updated regularly for the past year by issuing a new IPA and having users delete and reinstall the app. Lately when I archive and distribute the app it installs correctly, but it is a previous version from a few days ago with none of the recent changes. These are things as simple as text labels and alerts with the wrong text.

I've done everything I can think of, including:

- Confirming it builds and runs correctly in the simulator and when building directly to an iPhone. Everything works great in these cases.
- Cleaning the project.
- In the Organizer, deleting all archives and removing the project.
- Manually deleting the DerivedData folder.
- Renaming the IPA and updating the distribution plist to ensure that the file isn't somehow being cached on the web server.
- Deleting the entire project and doing a fresh checkout from SVN.

Even when I do all of these things together, so that I've completely removed the project from my computer and Xcode and re-archived it with a fresh checkout of the source files, it still archives an outdated version. Where could this be coming from? Should I just reinstall Xcode completely?

Comment: "having users delete and reinstall the app" - FYI, deleting the app is unnecessary and of course leads to lost user data.

Comment: Also another question, have you changed the bundle ID recently? Could it be that your device has two versions with the newer version hidden away on a different screen of icons?

Comment: The bundle ID hasn't been changed. I just verified that the app was completely removed and that I'm running the one that just installed, so there doesn't seem to be an old one on the device itself.

Comment: When you want to distribute a new archive, always use "Product -> Archive -> Distribute" not "Organizer->Distribute".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The network was caching it! The wireless network in my office is serving up a cached version of the IPA from yesterday, while an external network downloads the latest copy just fine. It's embarrassing that I never thought to check this, but I suppose the solution is often obvious in hindsight.

Thanks to Jake and Mike for the suggestions; I'm sure they will be helpful to others who come  across this question.

Comment: I am very hesitant to this. But when i restart my network. It really worked on my end. Thanks for the idea

Answer (score 0):

Since you have deleted and checked that your build files are clean from old rubbish, I would have a look at the actual source files and the project and make sure you are actually making your changes on the right place.

Right click on the files that you are working on in your project and select "Show in Finder" and see where they are actually located. Maybe they are in a different location than you would expect?

Do the same with the files under "Compile Sources" in your target, and make sure they are the same files and at the same location as the ones you have been editing.

It could be that if you at some point has fiddled around with your files and projects that you actually imported the wrong files and that you are editing different files than the ones included in your build. It happened to me once, I had to re-import lots of files to my project to get it working again.

Comment: This is a good suggestion, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to be the issue in this case. I used "Show in Finder" for both the files and the target's compile sources and they are all where they should be. I also opened the files in an external editor to confirm that the changes are actually being saved to the correct file by XCode.